# setup flutter app without android studio on windows

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

I want to create my first flutter app but the official doc says we must install android studio to run the app and test it but the android studio is so big and heavy and I am a web developer just trying to test my first flutter app and dont want to use the android studio.
any solution to run and develop an app in VS Code and windows?

Comment: We did you get that? I believe you can use VS Code on Windows to develop and test Flutter app.

Comment: run command "flutter doctor" give me error that i need to install android studio

Comment: did you read [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode) official flutter doc?

Comment: yes thank you i findout android studio message is not error and it is warning

Comment: yes thank you i findout android studio message is not error and it is warning

Answer (score 6):

It is very possible to use VS Code for Flutter without having installed Android Studio, however it's a little more involved. You'll need to download and install the Android SDK on its own, and without Android Studio you'll be missing a few things (like the UI for managing emulators, updating the SDK components, or editing assets like icons).

I tried for a while to work without it (I'm the developer of the VS Code extensions and installing it felt like admission that there are things missing there ) but after a while it turned out to be easier to just install it (especially updating SDK bits).

Answer (score 1):

an addition to @AbOo Saed answer, you need to install android sdks for you to begin development.
for you to be able to build your app with a custom package name run

```
flutter create --org com.packagename -i swift -a kotlin --description ' App Description' your_app_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always make flutter apps in Visual Studio Code using Flutter and Dart plugins, but to run them you'll need an emulator. This need can be eliminated by using an actual device connected via USB.
But what about other things like build tools, android SDK, CLI tools, etc. Things that aren't easy to get separately. Android studio saves you all this trouble.

My suggestion is to have Android Studio installed on the sidelines. Do all your work in VSCode, many people are happy with that. To occasionally configure stuff the studio will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

follow [this](https://medium.com/@quicky316/install-flutter-sdk-on-windows-without-android-studio-102fdf567ce4) medium article and install and follow every step.
new version of flutter needs android sdk 28 or higher so chnage `sdkmanager “system-images;android-27;default;x86_64”` to `sdkmanager “system-images;android-28;default;x86_64”` and other 27 to 28 too.
after installation, if you cant connect to the emulator try command `emulator -avd emulator-name` for example `emulator -avd nexus` and see whats the problem. for me it was

> Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4

so i download and install latest version from [here](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/) 
then its work perfectly